# Refresh Listview issue

Tags: ajax, listview, jquery-mobile, refresh

I have an issue with refreshing listview.

I have 2 pages within the same html file.
In both pages, I have a listview generated dynamical with Ajax:

```
<ul data-role="listview" data-filter="true" id="nestedList">
</ul>
```

And in the other one:

```
<ul data-role="listview" data-filter="true" id="secondList">
</ul>
```

After loading datas, I'm doing this:

```
$('#nestedList').html(dynamicNestedList);
$('#secondList').html(dynamicSecondList);
$('ul#nestedList').listview("refresh");
```

For the first page, everything is ok.
For the second page, I added a simple script which makes the refresh on the fly:

```
<script>
 $('ul#secondList').listview("refresh");
</script>
```

With jQueryMobile Beta1, I could go back to the first page and everything was still ok.
With jQueryMobile Beta2, when I go back to the first page, the listview is empty...

I tried to add the same "script" to refresh on the fly the first page. It does not work. When I go back to the first page, the "Loading" jQuery message is happening and never leaves..

I've heard about the "create" trigger of jQuery Mobile Beta 2, but I may not understand what it means really...

Any solution?

Answer (score 0):

You need to execute this in a live()

- http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0b2/#/demos/1.0b2/docs/api/events.html

Example:

```
$('#secondList_page_id').live('pageshow',function(event, ui) {
    $('#secondList').html(dynamicSecondList);
    $('ul#secondList').listview("refresh");
});

$('#nestedList_page_id').live('pageshow',function(event, ui) {
    $('#nestedList').html(dynamicNestedList);
    $('ul#nestedList').listview("refresh"); 
});
```

Comment: It seems that the nestedList content disappears when I switch to another page. And when I come back, even if I do a listview "refresh", the content is no longer here... It's strange because this does not affect the second list..

Comment: It works.. not as well as beta1 but it works good.
What is still strange is that the second list doesn't need that code, content stay in the list once it has been put in... while first list always lose its content when changing page...

Comment: to better debug you would need to add how you are using the dynamicNestedList